# How to initialize global variables via a function in C++

Tags: c++

I am learning C++. I want to have a function to initialize my variables. For example:

```
#include <iostream>

double a,b
void Initializer ( double x, double y)
{
    a = x;   //a and b are global variables.
    b = y;
}
int main()
{
    Initializer(0.,4.);
    std::cout<<a<<" "<<b<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

However, I get garbage for my global variables. For example I call `initializer(0.,4.)`, and I expect `a==0` and `b==4`; however when I print the values they are not 0,4 respectively.

Comment: This is obviously not the complete code, as it doesn't not compile. Please share the entire code.

Comment: The code will not compile.

Comment: FYI, you are using C++, not C.

Comment: What do you actually get?

Comment: If i correct your code it's working for me... show the exact code pls

Comment: After fixing the basic issues to get it to compile it works here: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/df9501c1a218e5f3

Comment: That's not initialisation, that's assignment. The variables were zero-initialised before `main` started. If you're getting garbage values, you're either not outputting your globals but something else with the same names, or something in your program has corrupted them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not see anything wrong about your code (except the formatting). This is the way you can initialize global variables in both C and C++ (complete, formatted example):

```
#include <iostream>

void Initializer(double x, double y);

using namespace std;

double a, b;

void Initializer(double x, double y) {
    a = x;  // a and b are global variables.
    b = y;
}
int main() {
    Initializer(0.0, 4.0);
    cout << a << " " << b << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Note that this line: `cout << a << " " << b << endl;` (together with the corresponding `include` and `using namespace std;`) is using C++ streams. The rest could also be compiled as C code.

It would also be more readable if you would provide doubles like that: `Initializer(0.0, 4.0);`.

Comment: The way to _initialize_ global variables in C and C++ is to add an _initializer_ to the definition.

Comment: I do not see much of an answer. You just confirm the question's code is (mostly) correct. Without additional information by OP it cannot be answered actually.

Comment: So you have picked a tiny mistake and pointed it out. This *is* the answer to the question, adding some details which OP didn't ask about but may be useful.

Comment: You are doing assignment not initialization. To initialize a global variable would be to write `double a = 0;`